# Avoid malloc in Serde

Tags: json, performance, rust, serde

I want to parse json as fast as possible using serde. To do this I want to completely avoid allocating objects on heap on a critical path. I use `deserialize_in_place` method, which does exactly what I need. I have a `PriceLevel` struct which has some `Vec`s inside it. This struct is allocated once and forever. When I parse jsons I reuse the same struct over and over again.

```
// holder is allocated once and forever
let mut holder = PriceLevel::zero();
// new deserializer is created for each new message
let mut deserializer = Deserializer::from_str(data);
Deserialize::deserialize_in_place(&mut deserializer, &mut holder).unwrap();
```

This approach allows to remove allocation of the struct itself and its internal `Vec`s, which is good. However, `Deserializer::from_str` constructor creates `Vec` inside it, and I have to create new instance of deserializer for each incoming json message. My question is how to avoid these internal allocations of the deserializer? One solution would be to have a `init` or `reset` method in deserializer, which would clear the internal state of the deserializer and allow it to parse another message. Or maybe there is a similar object which allows such reusing?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to make it work: `Deserializer` doesn't give access to the internal reader so you can't go and update that after your parse has completed, passing the reader by reference would only allow you to reuse it after dropping the deserializer, so you'd still have the issue of the internal `scratch` vec.

Comment: [issue 694](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/694) is basically what you want, but remains open.

Comment: "`Deserializer::from_str` constructor creates `Vec` inside it" while this is true, `Vec::new()` doesn't allocate. With my superficial understanding, it seems that the `Vec` is for scratchspace when parsing strings with unicode escapses (which by the way require allocation, no way around it). Are you sure you want to worry about this? (Also: "This approach allows to remove allocation of the struct itself and its internal Vecs" is imprecise: It allows you to reuse space allocated in previous iterations of a deserialization loop. But if this code runs once, your `Vec`s are allocated normally.)

Comment: If you want to remove allocations, you can use a `no_std` compatible library. For JSON there seems to be `serde-json-core` (<https://serde.rs/no-std.html>) available.

Comment: no_std feature doesn't even compile in my project. The compilation error comes from serde-json-core itself, not from my code. I wonder why.